# unable to update issue via email

Tags: redmine

I have redmine receiving emails via imap setup, at present new tasks can be created via email with no issue. If we want to update an issue via email it does not work. Some examples

An email sent with the following syntax works to crate the issue

email subject is new test task

Body of email contains

Project: test

Tracker: Activity

Assignee: user1

Some information on the task

Can see on the server the task is created https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbejL.jpg

This works fine no issues.

If a new email is sent that has the following syntax subject of [#8492]

Body of email contains

Assignee: user2

Nothing change, the assignee name is still that which was set in the first email.

No other items can be change via an update email to a task. Is there something else we need to do or change?

Comment: how is your command for creating tickets looking like?

Comment: @AleksandarPavić will update, we found that the test server we have was working fine, so either it is version specific or a plugin issue. Working on solving that at the moment. Can confirm a base 4.0 install works fine